# proving product of three consecutive numbers has a divisor $s^2 -1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For all $N≥0$, if $N=k(k+1)(k+2), k>1$ is the product of three consecutive non-negative integers, prove that $N$ is divisible by some number $s^2 -1, s>k$. I was able to figure out that if we take $s = k+1$, then $s^2-1|k(k+2)$, which means that $s^2-1|k(k+2)(k+1)$. However, is there some way that I could have found the expression $s^2 - 1$ without knowing it beforehand? In other words, if the questions were multiple choice with different expressions and asked you for the correct one, how would I directly get $s^2 - 1$ without trying each expression?

Comment: That conjecture is wrong. Let $k := 2$. Then there is no $s > k$ such that $s^{2} + 2$ divides $k(k+1)(k+2)$.

Comment: @Chou Thanks, I've changed the post now. It was a multiple choice problem, and I was only able to work it out by revealing the correct answer and then working backwards to figure out why it was correct. However, I would like a more direct way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When seeing $s^2-1$ you **immediately and unavoidably** must think of $(s-1)(s+1)$ and then of course immediately match that with $s=k+1$ from the given expression.